# Hibernate Transaction not successfully started when I change db name

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tomcat, jdbc

I'm deploying a web-app to a tomcat container, connected to a mysql container. When I deploy my war, after I created the MySQL database (inserted via `hibernate.cfg.xml`), all works well.

But, if I want to connect my web-app to a new database, created after I deploy my war to webapps/ folder, I have the following lines:

```
27-Feb-2017 09:47:36.199 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
27-Feb-2017 09:47:36.200 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
27-Feb-2017 09:52:03.503 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [controller.AccountController] in context with path [/ShoppingAT] threw exception
 org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:200)
    at model.AbstractModel.create(AbstractModel.java:137)
    at controller.AccountController.doPost(AccountController.java:113)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)     
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)      
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2445)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I solve this problem?

This is my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC^M
                "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"^M
                "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">^M
<hibernate-configuration>^M
    <session-factory>^M
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>^M
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>^M
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://172.19.0.3:3306/shine</property>^M
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>^M
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
          <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
           <mapping class="entities.Responsabile"/>
           <mapping class="entities.Utente"/>
    <!--       <mapping class="entities.Prodotti"/>  --> 
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My goal is to create a new (copied) web-app from my initial .war. So, I've renamed my war, deployed it to webapps/, and edited `hibernate.cfg.xml`. If I rename my war and point it to the initial db, it's all ok. This problem appears when I point to another db. In fact, in the logs, there is the "context path" of the initial web app (/ShoppingAT).

Comment: How are you switching to another database? Are you restarting the webapp after pointing to the other database? What is your config file? Also the stacktrace you posted doesn't seem to be complete (or at least: I would expect an exception cause in that stacktrace0.

Comment: 1. I've created my new db via php myadmin; 2. Deployed my new war; 3. Modify hibernate.cfg.xml to pointing to the new db. 4. restart tomcat container. See my edited log